# ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC - Model Binding - Dropdown List Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdown, model-binding, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a ViewModel something like this which contains two properties.

**UserSelectedState - String value**

**ListOfStateNames - This is a List of SelectListItem.**

I am able to bind the model to the View and the user sees the list of state names and makes one selection. I am posting it back to the controller and I am able to see the "UserSelectedState" value assigned correctly.

But, the "ListofStateNames" is empty in the Model when posted back.

Just trying to understand why it should be empty. Since it's the same Model which is populating the list items in the View.

Any explanation on why it is empty ?

Comment: A form  posts back the name/value controls of its successful form controls. You do not (and should not) create form controls for each property of each `SelectListItem`

Comment: Form Post back ! Right. I missed this part. I was thinking the entire "View Model Class" is being sent from client to the server during the post back using JSON serialization and MVC framework.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help.